# How to access a controller action from shared view in mvc 4 razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have create one view Index & on that view i have place one shared view on that view but now i have to call controller action from that shared view(_TraningList)

this is index view

For that i have do following thing

```
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_TrainingList.cshtml", Model.First().Categories)
 @Html.Partial("_ConsultingList")
 @Html.Partial("_UpcomingWebinarList")
```

this is Shared View

```
@model IEnumerable<QPS_MVC.BusinessLogic.CourseCategories>
<!--Training Box-->
<div class="bodyContentWrp">
@*@Html.Action("Index", "Trainings")*@
<h1>
    Training Programs</h1>
@*  <ul class="arw1">
            <li>Aerospace</li>
            <li>Agile</li>
            <li>APICS/SME Certifications</li>
            <li>ASQ Certifications</li>
            <li>FDA Related</li>
            <li>HR Related</li>
            <li>ISO Related</li>
            <li>IT Certifications</li>
            <li>Lean Six Sigma</li>
            <li>PMI Certifications</li>
        </ul>
*@
@foreach (QPS_MVC.BusinessLogic.CourseCategories item in Model)
{
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "", "Trainings", new { SelectedId = item.CategoryID },   null)</li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
}
<div class="clear">
</div>
<div class="readMore">
    <a href="#">Read More</a></div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
```

This is Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Courses> obj = new List<Courses>();

        if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0 && Request.QueryString["SelectedId"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["SelectedId"].ToString()))
        {

            obj = new CoursesApp().getAllCoursesById(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["SelectedId"].ToString()));

        }
        else
        {
            obj = new CoursesApp().getAllCourses();
            obj = new CoursesApp().getAllCoursesById(obj.First().Categories.First().CategoryID);
        }
        //if (ViewData["CategoryId"] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewData["CategoryId"].ToString()))
        //{
        //    obj = new CoursesApp().getAllCourses();
        //    obj = new CoursesApp().getAllCoursesById(obj.First().Categories.First().CategoryID);
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    obj = new CoursesApp().getAllCoursesById(int.Parse(ViewData["CategoryId"].ToString()));
        //}
        return View(obj);
    }
```

So basically i want to call this index action from Shared View _trainingList 
i have done above thing but i can't get success so please any one help me out.

Comment: You shouldn't really call an **additional** method that doesn't take any parameters in your views. You could put that `List<Courses>` in your model and then just put the logic from that Index view into your shared view.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`RenderAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction(v=vs.118).aspx)

> Invokes a child action method and renders the result inline in the parent view.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Action", "Controller"); }
```